# inheritFromWidgetOfExactType is deprecated use dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType instead

Tags: flutter, dart

Since the release of Flutter 1.12 my following code:

```dart
static MyInheritedWidget of(BuildContext context) {
  return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(MyInheritedWidget) as MyInheritedWidget;
}
```

warns with the following:

> 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType instead. This feature was deprecated after v1.12.1..
>   Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.

But when I try to replace it, it does not work:

```dart
static MyInheritedWidget of(BuildContext context) {
  return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType(MyInheritedWidget) as MyInheritedWidget;
}
```

Does someone know how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 189, accepted):

The API changed slightly.

Now instead of taking a `Type` as argument, the method is generic.

Before:

```dart
final widget = context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(MyInheritedWidget) as MyInheritedWidget;
```

After:

```dart
final widget = context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MyInheritedWidget>();
```

Note that the cast is no longer necessary

Comment: Thank you! I found it too here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/widgets/inherited_test.dart

Answer (score 6):

**[InheritFromWidgetOfExactType](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/inheritFromWidgetOfExactType.html) method is deprecated , Use [dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType.html)  method instead.**

**Example of a replacement**:

**Before :** with [InheritFromWidgetOfExactType](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/inheritFromWidgetOfExactType.html)

```
static Name of(BuildContext context) {
  return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(Name);  //here
}
```

**Now** with [dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType.html)  (Recommanded)

```
static Name of(BuildContext context) {
  return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Name>();  //here
}
```

> Now instead of taking a `Type` as argument, **The method is generic .**
> Brief `<...>()` instead of `(...)`