# How to fix inheritFromWidgetOfExactType error from notifier package

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to upgrade an old project. This project use [notifier](https://pub.dev/packages/notifier) package and it occurs as following compile error.

```
pub.dartlang.org/notifier-1.0.2/lib/notifier_provider.dart:16:21 Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'
```

I've checked and there is no new version for notifier package.
We don't want to downgrade flutter version.
How can I fix this issue? or Can't we use notifier package anymore?

Answer (score 0):

- You can use [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html)
- If you need to use the notifier package, you can grab the code and update the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304242/inheritfromwidgetofexacttype-is-deprecated-use-dependoninheritedwidgetofexacttyp)