# how to solve Error: 'MyInheritedWidget' isn't a type

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

when i try to build my flutter project, i got an error like "inheritFromWidgetOfExactType is deprecated use dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType instead", so followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304242/inheritfromwidgetofexacttype-is-deprecated-use-dependoninheritedwidgetofexacttyp) answer and changed my code to

```
static ChewieController of(BuildContext context) {
    final chewieControllerProvider =
    context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MyInheritedWidget>();
    return chewieControllerProvider.controller;
}
```

but now i am having a error Error: "MyInheritedWidget' isn't a type. how do i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<MyInheretedWidget>` with the actual name of your widget. i e `<ChewieController>`.